# Loki connection refused on Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

caller=client.go:349 component=client host=loki:3100 msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=-1 error="Post "http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push": dial tcp 172

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem as you.
Finally I found the missing rbac.
I solved it by the following method:

1. get sa loki-promtail

`kubectl get sa -n loki`

```
NAME                SECRETS   AGE
default             1         17h
loki                1         41m
loki-grafana        1         41m
loki-grafana-test   1         41m
loki-promtail       1         41m
```

2. create ClusterRole

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: promtail-clusterrole
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
    - nodes
    - services
    - pods
    verbs:
    - get
    - watch
    - list
```

3. create ClusterRoleBinding

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: promtail-clusterrolebinding
subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: loki-promtail  # your promtail sa
      namespace: loki
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: promtail-clusterrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```